# How to add the "Sign In with LinkedIn" product for apps that have r_basicprofile (#linkedin)

Tags: linkedin-api

I have several applications originally defined using the V1 LinkedIn API requesting only the r_basicprofile scope. Some also requested the r_emailaddress scope.

Those that requested both scopes appear to now have the product "Sign In for LinkedIn" assigned and the V2 API scope r_liteprofile. Those that only requested scope r_basicprofile appear to not have any products assigned and do not have r_liteprofile.

Currently applications without r_liteprofile are generating an error to the effect of "'r_liteprofile' is not authorized for your application".

How do I add the r_liteprofile scope to my application? I tried adding the "Sign In for LinkedIn" product but it is showing "Review in progress". How long does the review take?

The desired goal is to have end users authenticate and I only need the data elements provided by the r_liteprofile.

Any help that can be provided would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You will get better answers if your provide a minimal, complete, reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Similar behavior shows up if you create a new app:

1) go to https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps
2) click "Create App"
3) provide:
3.1) App Name
3.2) Company
3.3) App Description
3.4) App Logo
3.5) Privacy Policy
3.6) Business Email
4) Accept the default products
5) Aggree to API Terms of Us
6) Press "Create App"
7) Navigate to "Products" menu and select "Product Requests"
8) See that products are now "Review in progress"

Comment: The "Sign In for LinkedIn" product is now getting approved after about 1 minute, making the issue moot.